# Why am I getting an error message "Target class [RefbrgsTableSeeder] does not exist" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm trying to figure out the error in my command:

php artisan db:seed

The error message is 
`Target class [RefbrgsTableSeeder] does not exist`

However when I checked my seeder class 
I have this:

```
use App\Refbrg;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RefbrgsTableSeeder extends Seeder
```

Can I ask for an explanation why this happens.
And can you give me a hint on resolving my seeding.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: run php artisan compose dump-autoload and then check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

normally this happen when you use copy\paste for other seeder classes while you should use:

```
php artisan make:seeder MyClassSeeder
```

more about making seeders in:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding#writing-seeders